# Jenkins failing build when not finding ".part" files

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, release

I've created a Jenkins job for maven releases. When doing "release:perform" the build fails with messages of this kind:

***Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/inject/guice-bean/1.4.2/guice-bean-1.4.2.pom.part (No such file or directory)***

The file changes sometimes, but the kind of error is always the same.
When performing the release manually (aka on my own machine) the error does not happen.

My job run the following commands:

- **mvn clean install**
- **mvn release:clean release:prepare -e -B**
- **mvn -X release:perform -e -Dusername='username' -Dpassword='password' -Darguments="-Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true"**

I believe it's related to space on disk or something similar to that. Is there any kind of config to fix it?

ps: the slaves are not running on containers yet

Thanks in advance